# Autogenerate dummy documentation in the source code for Python in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, plugins, documentation, pydev

At the time I am documenting a lot of my code (Python) and I was wondering if there is a plugin to Eclipse that can automatically generate a doc string for my functions, like visual studio does it for C# when writing `///` over a method.

I have been searching around for a solution, but I had no luck - do any of you know a solution?

**Example:**

From my parameter list on a method the "dummy" documentation will be created under my method definition as shown below:

```
def myFunction(self, a, b):
    """

    :param a:
    :type a:
    :param b:
    :type b:
    :return:
    :rtype:
    """
    return 'Hello, world'
```

Comment: I think that this is against, in general, the spirit of python. Parameters should be self documenting via their possibly verbose name. Python uses type inference, thus, a unit test should fail if the argument type doesn't match the intended parameter type. A one line documentation should suffice.

Comment: In many ways I agree with you, however, I do not thing that my end-user does. He has no access to the unit tests, and I believe that a nice documented code which elaborate a bit more than the names of my parameters make his life easier and he can get up and running with my API a bit faster. (and with fewer costs)

Comment: I see your point, but I would leave off the type information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, according to [this doc](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_assistants.html), if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> on a method name, you will get what you need.

For your example (EDIT : if you set the option PyDev>Editor>Code Style>Docstrings>Doctag generation to always to get the type of the param), you will get :

```
def myFunction(self, a, b):
    '''

    @param a:
    @type a:
    @param b:
    @type b:
    '''
    return 'Hello, world'
```

Comment: I have not found that, but it is very close :) and I can see that in my preferences in Eclipse i can change the single-qoute to double, but, because of my documentation tool (Sphinx) the '@' must be changed to ':' to work, but i cant really see if that is possible!

Comment: @aweis : I found how to add the type of the parameter (not yet how to change the @ into :)

Comment: Hi, some how I don't have the type anymore, what did you do to get that automatically generated too? - If i get the type parameter also, I can live with the fact that i need to manually change the @'s

Comment: Very nice, thank you :) Funny enough, when changing the doctag value, I get asked about 'parameter prefix', maybe there is a feature that is not fully implemented in PyDev :)